# How to wait for a function to complete before next statement is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which executes the following function when clicked :

```
async function VerifyData() {
    if(condition1) {
        MessageBox("Operation Not Allowed.");
        return;
    }
    
    //Code to form the Ids is here
    
    let result = await additionalCheck(Ids); //Passing Ids to Check
    if(result) {
        $("#Window").data("kendoWindow").open().center();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The `additionalCheck(Ids)` function is as follows :

```
function additionalCheck(Ids) 
{
    let count = 0;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Data")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "text",
        data: { ids: Ids },
        success: function (data) {
            isSuccess = true;
            count = data;
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }).done(function () {
        $.unblockUI();
        if (isSuccess) {
            if (count > 0) {
                MessageBox("Operation Invalid.");
                resolve(false); // This should prevent the verifyData() function also to terminate its execution
            }
            else {
                resolve(true);//It should return to the previous function and execute the next line.
            }
        } else {
            MessageBox("Error. Please try again.");
            return;
        }
    });
    });
}
```

The issue I am facing is when the `additionalCheck(Ids)` function is called, the code doesn't wait for the execution of the ajax statement in it and instead opens the Kendo Window before the function execution is completed.I want the `VerifyData()` function to wait for the `additionalCheck(Ids)` function execution before executing the statement after the call of the function.

I have tried using `Promise` but it didn't work for me (maybe I did not do it correctly).How can I achieve this?

Comment: Move `$("#Window").data("kendoWindow").open().center();` into the `done` callback function.

Comment: If you have already tried to solve this on your own, put your attempt into the question so we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There are also other lines of code which I haven't added here and I have similar other functions with different operations so I cannot add the line into the done function as `additionalCheck(Ids)` is called for every other function.

Comment: @ChrisG I made a modification to the code I attempted and it's working for me now. I am updating the question(which is basically my answer).

Comment: Your question hasn't been edited yet? Also, feel free to remove the question instead (although it's probably no longer possible now :/ )

Comment: @ChrisG I have updated the question and yes I know I cannot remove it now. But thank you

Comment: You have used the anti-pattern from the answer below. You do not need a secondary promise. Here's the proper way https://jsfiddle.net/faozksjm/ (asked and answered hundreds of times)

Answer (score -1):

To clarify things, javascript does wait for the execution of the additionalCheck function, but it will not wait for the completion of the ajax request, which is asynchronous, you will need to use a promise :

```
//Passing Ids to Check
additionalCheck(Ids).then(() => {
    $("#Window").data("kendoWindow").open().center();
})
```

```
function additionalCheck(Ids) 
{

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        let count = 0;
    
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Data")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "text",
            data: { ids: Ids },
            success: function (data) {
                isSuccess = true;
                count = data;
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }).done(function () {
            $.unblockUI();
            if (isSuccess) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    MessageBox("Operation Invalid.");
                    reject();
                }
                else {
                 resolve();
                }
            } else {
                MessageBox("Error. Please try again.");
                reject();
            }
        });
    
      })
    }
```

but in that particular case like pointed out in the comments, its more simple to move the  `$("#Window").data("kendoWindow").open().center();` in the .done()

Comment: $.ajax() returns a Promise so no need to wrap the call in a new one.

Comment: ajax does return a promise, but here a new  promise should be made, to customize the scenarios in which the promise is rejected or resolved

Comment: No, absolutely not. Wrapping a promise returning call in a Promise is an antipattern. What you do is return the ajax call and await the function call.

Comment: That does not work, because the promise will be resolved if the request pass, even when OP conditions are not met (count > 0 ...). Perhaps the server should return an error when there is no data to allow us to use the promise of  $.ajax

Comment: Which means you should restructure your code so loading data from a server and handling it are separated concerns. Anyway, this question is one of the most infamous JS dupes of all times and gets asked about on a daily basis. It should be closed as dupe as soon as it appears, not answered (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254895/general-javascript-asynchronicity-reference-for-close-voting)

Comment: @Lk77 Of course it works. You can simply check `count` before returning. [Simplified example here.](https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/2815856cb991d348be68493a8019139a)

Comment: There is still two promises anyway, you don't pass $.ajax promise to the VerifyData method, VerifyData will get the promise from async, i prefer my code in term of readability to be honest